# Could we mention accepting answers in the low quality review "thank you" auto comment?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, comments

When I was walking through the low quality review queue, I found an OP posted answer like this:

> Thanks for the two comments all I had to do was input:
>
> `<the solution>` worked like a charm thanks to both of the guys
>   who commented!

The solution was in one of the answers to their question. Well, obviously enough, for such post I would recommend deletion and choose this prefabricated comment option:

> **This is a “thank you” comment**
>
> “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient
>   reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you
>   found helpful.”

This comment tells the OP what to avoid the next time and how to reward people who answered their question, but it doesn't mention how to close the case - how to accept an answer.

Can we have a note about accepting answers in the prefabricated “thank you” comment for the OP (the one added for the OP answering their own question with “thank you”)?

---

<sup>**Steps to find this comment:**

1. go to [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) review queue

2. find a self-answer (this may take some time!)

3. click the *Delete* button

4. look for *This is a “thank you” comment* radio button</sup>

Comment: So, extend that one's text if the answer is from the OP. Good idea.

Answer (score 36):

Yes, the canned comment that comes from marking an answer as `This is a "thank you" comment` should be changed to mention accepting an answer if the flagged answer is from the OP.

How about the following:

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. At your discretion, you may [accept one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to the answer that you think is the best.  Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful.

(I added the second sentence for the case that the "thank you" answer is from the OP.)

Comment: It is not clear to me: are you talking about posting an _answer_ as a "thank you". Or posting a _comment_ ? The former is obviously worst -- but in both cases, we should strongly suggest voting up and/or accepting the answer...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'm talking about an answer that was already posted as a "thank you". At this point, someone has already flagged such a post, presumably as "not an answer".  My suggested text adds to the canned comment text that is posted as a comment on the reviewer's behalf when such a post is reviewed and the thank you "answer" was posted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the new users do not learn Stack Overflow's accepting and upvoting mechanism quickly.
When I joined Stack Overflow I was also not accepting answers, because I did not know how to do that. I was commenting "Thank you it worked great".

Some users tend to not give answers to such new users or to users with a low accepting percentage ratio.

I usually reply to their thank you in the way below:

> Thank you on Stack Overflow is accepting answers and upvote them.

So if we give any pop-up or text message to new users or keep reminding them of a low accepting answers percentage, then they will start to learn this quickly.

Comment: We stopped displaying the accept rate percentage a long time ago.

Comment: @S.L.Barth even if it's not displayed directly, it doesn't mean some people couldn't still evaluate it

Comment: `<oldguymode>` - Back in the old days we tried to learn the rules of the house before posting - `</oldguymode>`

Comment: Brand new users won't have the rep to upvote.